# Read a txt file content in Rhomobile

Tags: file, rhomobile

I have a txt file stored in file system. I want to read the content of that file in single go and assign it to a varialble.
whichever function i try i get this error

Error: undefined method 'root' for #

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read a file in Ruby using the `File.read` function:

```
s = File.read 'your_file_name.txt'
```

Now, the variable `s` will have the file's content.